# Can not find symbol volley

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, android-volley

```
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

 import code.studio.v.R;
 import code.studio.v.volley.RequestQueue;
```

Android studio is showing an error . Can not resolve symbol volley. I have cloned volley and added it as a module. My package name is code.studio.v

The following is my build.gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 21
buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "code.studio.v"
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 21
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),   'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
  }
 } 

   dependencies {
   compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'
  }
```

the following is settings.gradle file .

```
include ':app', ':volley'
```

Comment: Please check this :

I have already answered here.
[http://stackoverflow.com/a/32367416/4018207][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32367416/4018207

Comment: @MamataGelanee still red.i tried  compile project(':volley') .

Comment: @MamataGelanee still red.i tried  compile project(':volley') but gradle console saysBUILD SUCCESSFUL.

Comment: remove all your error imports and try to import again using ctrl+enter . Plus rebuild your project..!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have imported volley library as a separate module then you have to add dependency  *compile project(':yourVolleyModule')* into your app's build.gradle. Now, Sync your gradle and i hope it will work

Answer (score 2):

remove module dependencies and add library dependencies..using following steps

[image]

1. Right Click on project - Module Setting

[image]

2. Go to dependencies- click plus(+) symbol

[image]

3. type volley and enter.. select the4thfloor dependencies

Finally sync gradle and run